# Website indexed as google.com and all pages are excluded

Tags: php, indexing, google-search-console

I have a problem with some website which is not shown in Google search.

I connected it to Google Search Concole and when I try to "Test Live url" each of subpages I see in "VIEW TESTED PAGE" a screenshot from main Google.com page. 
Info about Indexing:

```
Indexing allowed? - Yes
User-declared canonical - None
Google-selected canonical - https://www.google.com/
```

But I set canonical url address using tag:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="..." />
```

Additionally I have 96 erros and 1.64K pages excluded.

In URL Inspection there is info:
"Duplicate, submitted URL not selected as canonical"

The domain had wrong DNS record for some time:

```
"v=spf1 a mx include:_spf.google.com include:_spf. acesender.com ~all"
```

When I checked this page to look for microdata here:

```
https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool
```

Google changed my URL to

```
http://www.google.com/#spf=1567541864681
```

and showed me HTML code of www.google.com

Could someone tell me what cloud be wrong with this website and what should I do to change it?

---

When the home page was served by static file index.html it has been correctly indexed but the other pages are not. There is old version of PHP Fusion. Now I need to find what do this in PHP Fussion 6 / code.

**/index.html**

```
​Request URL: https://domain.pl/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 304 
Remote Address: 85.128.203.33:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
date: Fri, 06 Sep 2019 12:18:23 GMT
etag: "10575-591e1629bf811"
last-modified: Fri, 06 Sep 2019 12:14:51 GMT
server: Apache/2
status: 304
vary: Accept-Encoding
:authority: domain.pl
:method: GET
:path: /
:scheme: https
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,pt;q=0.6
cache-control: max-age=0
cookie: fusion_visited=yes; _ga=GA1.2.1597082664.1565961521; _gid=GA1.2.1371478008.1567772276; _gat_gtag_UA_143710154_1=1
if-modified-since: Fri, 06 Sep 2019 12:14:51 GMT
if-none-match: "10575-591e1629bf811"
sec-fetch-mode: navigate
sec-fetch-site: none
sec-fetch-user: ?1
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36
```

**index.php**

```
Request URL: https://domain.pl/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: 85.128.203.33:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
content-encoding: br
content-length: 11091
content-type: text/html
date: Fri, 06 Sep 2019 12:22:12 GMT
link: <https://domain.pl/>; rel=canonical"
server: Apache/2
status: 200
vary: Accept-Encoding
:authority: domain.pl
:method: GET
:path: /
:scheme: https
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,pt;q=0.6
cache-control: max-age=0
cookie: fusion_visited=yes; _ga=GA1.2.1597082664.1565961521; _gid=GA1.2.1371478008.1567772276; _gat_gtag_UA_143710154_1=1
sec-fetch-mode: navigate
sec-fetch-site: none
sec-fetch-user: ?1
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem where in PHP Fusion framework. I didn't find the solution. We decided to change the website.